# Is my RVM ruby version incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I deployed a web app today to my production server, I had an error and in my passenger backtrace I noticed this:

```
/var/www/sites/exampleapp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb
```

This repeats a few times so I won't paste the entire backtrace.

However, I made sure that on my server ruby 1.9.2 was the default for rvm:

```
jeff@bigbox:/var/www/sites$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
```

At the bottom of my backtrace I have this:

```
/home/jeff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb
```

Is my app in fact using 1.9.2, if so what is this 1.9.1 stuff and can I safely ignore it? I don;t even have 1.9.1 on this box nor do I have a system ruby installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [1.9.2 release announcement](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/08/18/ruby-1-9.2-released/):

> Standard library is installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1
>
> This version is a "library compatible
> version." Ruby 1.9.2 is almost 1.9.1
> compatible, so the library is
> installed in the 1.9.1 directory.

Even though you still see stuff installed in a 1.9.1 directory, it is using 1.9.2